# Is there a tool to select some code in Visual Studio and have it show the corresponding MSIL?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cil

Lately I've found myself constantly running ILDASM to study the MSIL output of my programs.

Are there any utilities to streamline this?  Ideally, it would be nice to select some source code and have it compile, disassemble and emit the selected C# code in MSIL.

Anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

I think that [RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/) have bought the IP to this tool now.  I'm fairly sure that there is a VS plugin which integrates to it to allow you to run this from vs.

[.Net Reflector Plugin](http://www.testdriven.net/reflector/)
[image]
<sub>(source: [mutantdesign.co.uk](http://www.mutantdesign.co.uk/reflector/TestWithReflector.gif))</sub>

Comment: @Timur Fanshteyn, Camtasia is the most popular one that I know of.

Comment: It's not my recording, i've taken it from the reflector website, just the picture was quite appropriate for the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [testdriven.net](http://www.testdriven.net/) an awesome unit testing plugin that gives you the ability to right click on any member and view it in reflector.

Answer (score 1):

Open the .dll in reflector, select any function in any class, and select IL as the language to decompile to. I don't think you're looking for a level more granular than that.